# Reading extracting data javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am developping a node js project.I have a zip file i want to extract it then i read one of the files inside my extracted zip.
The problem that i has that even i code the function for extraction before the readfile function that i call it in the callback.
I always has no such file or directory error like the readfile is passed before the extraction.Help!!

This is my code

```
var unzip = require('unzip');
const fs = require('fs');
var stream =  fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'files/em' }));
stream.on('finish', function () {
  fs.readFileSync('files/em/data.json') ;//read the extracted file but always the extraction passed after this
});
```

Comment: Try to also listen on error event to ensure that it really extracts the files successfully. `stream.on('error', console.log)`

Comment: yes it extracts the file succefuly but it did the readfile before the extraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't observe the right event. The `'finish'` event of `createReadStream()` is triggered before the unzip process occurs. You should instead listen to the `'close'` event of the unzip process to be sure the extraction is done.

```
const unzip = require('unzip');
const fs = require('fs');

const zipFilePath = 'files/data.zip'

let extract = unzip.Extract({ path: 'files/em' })
let stream = fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath).pipe(extract);

extract.on('close', () => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync('files/em/data.json') ;
  console.log(data.toString())  // print your unziped json file
})
```

Answer (score 0):

path should be a directory, 'unzip.Extract({ path: 'files/em' })'